# Can we use any jar file (made from java code) in android projects?

Tags: java, android, android-library

I have a class which uses imports like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.GlyphVector;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;

public class FontEx{        
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

We know that Android does't come with java.awt.font.GlyphVector or font.FontRenderContext.

Can i make jar file for this class "FontEx" and import it directly in my android eclipse project and use it???

...............................................................................
..................................................................................

```
**package org.newdawn.slick.font;

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.font.GlyphMetrics;
import java.awt.font.GlyphVector;

import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.UnicodeFont;

/**
 * Represents the glyph in a font for a unicode codepoint.
 * 
 * @author Nathan Sweet <misc@n4te.com>
 */
public class Glyph {
    /** The code point in which this glyph is found */
    private int codePoint;
    /** The width of this glyph in pixels */
    private short width;
    /** The height of this glyph in pixels */
    private short height;
    /** The offset on the y axis to draw the glyph at */
    private short yOffset;
    /** True if the glyph isn't defined */
    private boolean isMissing;
    /** The shape drawn for this glyph */
    private Shape shape;
    /** The image generated for this glyph */
    private Image image;

    /**
     * Create a new glyph
     * 
     * @param codePoint The code point in which this glyph can be found
     * @param bounds The bounds that this glrph can fill
     * @param vector The vector this glyph is part of
     * @param index The index of this glyph within the vector
     * @param unicodeFont The font this glyph forms part of
     */
    public Glyph(int codePoint, Rectangle bounds, GlyphVector vector, int index, UnicodeFont unicodeFont) {
        this.codePoint = codePoint;

        GlyphMetrics metrics = vector.getGlyphMetrics(index);
        int lsb = (int)metrics.getLSB();
        if (lsb > 0) lsb = 0;
        int rsb = (int)metrics.getRSB();
        if (rsb > 0) rsb = 0;

        int glyphWidth = bounds.width - lsb - rsb;
        int glyphHeight = bounds.height;
        if (glyphWidth > 0 && glyphHeight > 0) {
            int padTop = unicodeFont.getPaddingTop();
            int padRight = unicodeFont.getPaddingRight();
            int padBottom = unicodeFont.getPaddingBottom();
            int padLeft = unicodeFont.getPaddingLeft();
            int glyphSpacing = 1; // Needed to prevent filtering problems.
            width = (short)(glyphWidth + padLeft + padRight + glyphSpacing);
            height = (short)(glyphHeight + padTop + padBottom + glyphSpacing);
            yOffset = (short)(unicodeFont.getAscent() + bounds.y - padTop);
        }

        shape = vector.getGlyphOutline(index, -bounds.x + unicodeFont.getPaddingLeft(), -bounds.y + unicodeFont.getPaddingTop());

        isMissing = !unicodeFont.getFont().canDisplay((char)codePoint);
    }

    /**
     * The unicode codepoint the glyph represents.
     * 
     * @return The codepoint the glyph represents
     */
    public int getCodePoint () {
        return codePoint;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the font does not have a glyph for this codepoint.
     * 
     * @return True if this glyph is not defined in the given code point
     */
    public boolean isMissing () {
        return isMissing;
    }

    /**
     * The width of the glyph's image.
     * 
     * @return The width in pixels of the glyphs image
     */
    public int getWidth () {
        return width;
    }

    /**
     * The height of the glyph's image.
     * 
     * @return The height in pixels of the glyphs image
     */
    public int getHeight () {
        return height;
    }

    /**
     * The shape to use to draw this glyph. This is set to null after the glyph is stored 
     * in a GlyphPage.
     * 
     * @return The shape drawn for this glyph
     */
    public Shape getShape () {
        return shape;
    }

    /**
     * Set the shape that should be drawn for this glyph
     * 
     * @param shape The shape that should be drawn for this glyph
     */
    public void setShape(Shape shape) {
        this.shape = shape;
    }

    /**
     * The image to use for this glyph. This is null until after the glyph is stored in a 
     * GlyphPage.
     * 
     * @return The image that has been generated for this glyph
     */
    public Image getImage () {
        return image;
    }

    /**
     * Set the image that has been generated for this glyph
     * 
     * @param image The image that has been generated for this glyph
     */
    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    /**
     * The distance from drawing y location to top of this glyph, causing the glyph to sit 
     * on the baseline.
     * 
     * @return The offset on the y axis this glyph should be drawn at
     */
    public int getYOffset() {
        return yOffset;
    }
}**
```

Answer (score 1):

If the FontEx class depends on GlyphVector and FontRenderContext, then no - packaging into a jar file won't make the class any more usable.

Comment: Soryy i'm fresh to android, please state that then what should i do so that i could use GlyphVector and FontRenderContext in my FontEx class. Using these i have to calculate Acent and Decent of each Glyph in GlyphVector. Android does't seem to work out these things.. i wonder if i could implement it in a class and make them available in jar and use that jar in droid project.. ??

Comment: You don't have GlyphVectors in Android, so there's no Acent or Decent to calculate. What are you trying to achieve? How would you use that information, had it been available?

Comment: Please see Glyph class in edit of question.. I am trying to implement this idea..

Comment: Actually I am trying to make a framework to display Arabic text with properly positioned vovel character. In android the vovel characters overlap on other characters. I am wondering if i could calculate top and bottom of each character and i consiquently i can calculate the desired position of diacritics and text characters. And using canvas i can print the text..

Comment: I can't really help you with that. All I'm saying is, you cannot use GlyphVector. There's a Paint.FontMetrics class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.FontMetrics.html) in Android, maybe you can use that?